# I'm trying to install Unreal engine 4

Tags: ubuntu, unreal-engine4

error when running  the  make command in the directory after running ./GenerateProjectFiles.sh

```
bash "/home/heisenberg/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh" CrashReportClient Linux Shipping  
Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
Building CrashReportClient...
Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (/home/heisenberg/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release).
Creating makefile for CrashReportClient (no existing makefile)
ERROR: Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='/home/heisenberg/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v14_clang-8.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/clang++', CommandLine=' --version', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
         at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x002dc] in <23340a11bb41423aa895298bf881ed68>:0 
         at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in <23340a11bb41423aa895298bf881ed68>:0 
         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
         at UnrealBuildTool.LinuxToolChain.DetermineCompilerVersion () [0x000e0] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.LinuxToolChain..ctor (System.String InArchitecture, UnrealBuildTool.LinuxPlatformSDK InSDK, System.Boolean InPreservePSYM, UnrealBuildTool.LinuxToolChainOptions InOptions) [0x002c5] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.LinuxPlatform.CreateToolChain (UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) [0x0005d] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.CreateToolchain (UnrealBuildTool.UnrealTargetPlatform Platform) [0x00014] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.Build (UnrealBuildTool.BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, UnrealBuildTool.ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, System.Boolean bIsAssemblingBuild, Tools.DotNETCommon.FileReference SingleFileToCompile) [0x00053] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.CreateMakefile (UnrealBuildTool.BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, UnrealBuildTool.TargetDescriptor TargetDescriptor, UnrealBuildTool.ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet) [0x00141] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Build (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] TargetDescriptors, UnrealBuildTool.BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, UnrealBuildTool.ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, UnrealBuildTool.BuildOptions Options, Tools.DotNETCommon.FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile) [0x0001a] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Execute (Tools.DotNETCommon.CommandLineArguments Arguments) [0x002b4] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0 
         at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main (System.String[] ArgumentsArray) [0x00291] in <dc480436ddaf4a07bf1ccbd367fb0a35>:0
Makefile:207: recipe for target 'CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping' failed
make: *** [CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping] Error 5
```

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to run the command `/home/heisenberg/Downloads/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v14_clang-8.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/clang++`.  On my computer, that file did not exist...but there was a file in that directory named `clang`.  I changed that file name to clang++ (`cp clang clang++`) and was able to successfully get past that error.

*However*, I then got a different error when running the `make` command.  At that point, I gave up on using the `release` branch.  I switched over to the `4.24` branch, and was able to build the project successfully.