# problem in Unreal Engine while generating Project files

Tags: unreal-engine4

I copied this command from udemy course and I have a problem in execution of that command

The command is `./GeneratingProjectFiles` and `make -j`
[image]

```
WARNING: Exception while generating include data for UE4Editor: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='/home/harshit/UnrealEngine/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v13_clang-7.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/clang++', CommandLine=' --version', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
               at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x002dc] in <23340a11bb41423aa895298bf881ed68>:0 
               at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in <23340a11bb41423aa895298bf881ed68>:0 
               at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
               at UnrealBuildTool.LinuxToolChain.DetermineCompilerVersion () [0x000e0] in <1554e506fb8846fe968267b0a1f18cec>:0 
               at UnrealBuildTool.LinuxToolChain..ctor (System.String InArchitecture, UnrealBuildTool.LinuxPlatformSDK InSDK, System.Boolean InPreservePSYM, UnrealBuildTool.LinuxToolChainOptions InOptions) [0x00267] in <1554e506fb8846fe968267b0a1f18cec>:0 
               at UnrealBuildTool.LinuxPlatform.CreateToolChain (UnrealBuildTool.CppPlatform CppPlatform, UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) [0x0004c] in <1554e506fb8846fe968267b0a1f18cec>:0 
               at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.CreateToolchain (UnrealBuildTool.CppPlatform CppPlatform) [0x00019] in <1554e506fb8846fe968267b0a1f18cec>:0
```

I hope you can see my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like it can't find a file at the location `/home/harshit/UnrealEngine/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v13_clang-7.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/clang++`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to install Unreal engine 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477245/im-trying-to-install-unreal-engine-4)